# Network Printer (\\MFP-05163476) is not accessible

Tags: networking, network-printer

I want to use Toshiba e-Studio 452 as a network printer in Windows 7 32bit. I configured the IP address of this printer as

IPv4:

```
IP :  192.168.0.100
DG :  255.255.255.0
SM :  192.168.0.1
```

SMB : Enabled

```
IP  : 192.168.0.100
```

and assign IP address in Win 7 as

```
IP :  192.168.0.101
DG :  255.255.255.0
SM :  192.168.0.1
```

When I want to access the printer named (\MFP-05163476) from network it show "\MFP-05163476 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resources. Contact the admission of this server to find out if you have access permission. The account is not authorized to log in from this station."

[screenshot of problem & ip configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDpp.jpg)

Please help me

Comment: Have you tried `\\192.168.0.100` instead?

Comment: Yes. But not working.

Comment: It is a printer. Why do you treat it as a file share?

Comment: It is a printer and scanner also. All scanned file store in this location that i want to access. There is also Print,  PCL6, PCL3 option. In win XP 2 i just click PCL6 and install the driver and    print documents from computer. But in Win 7 I cannot access the printer.